# Apache Echarts Grouped and Stacked bars

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I've got grouped bars (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-stack-normalization) and stacked (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-stack-normalization) bars working independently. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a 3rd data dimension to add grouped AND stacked bars on data like this

```
  dataset: [
    {
      source: [
        ['entity_name', 'entity_id', 'time', 'uptime', 'offtime', 'downtime'],
        ['Machine 1', 11, '2024-02-12T00:00:00.000Z', 2075, 2100, 3758],
        ['Machine 1', 11, '2024-02-13T00:00:00.000Z', 8385, 175, 20240],
        ['Machine 2', 12, '2024-02-12T00:00:00.000Z', 2018, 2100, 3815],
        ['Machine 2', 12, '2024-02-13T00:00:00.000Z', 15917, 1895, 5420]
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here's a link to an ECharts [fiddle](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-stack-normalization&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAmBDMWDOApmAFywDaa6ylVsewArgE4DGBpFttZA5AdJDABPAPrQsAWwI8ANLD4CIwkRAyz5kKep4NwELXJ7AAZsc3TDGYAHdFWgLoyaXXgFksLABYRoBWAEZ1f39DACYABlCAFgBaSJj_UIAVcPDiVPTwgDpU8IAtdQiAdgBWOVD_VLkAZlKADkdnbh53Lx8_QLlgsMjY-P9qlLSM1JzUgrk66rqygNLy3vDGrio3D29fWFCg0J7ouNCE5JHh7NyJrfD_OvLK8Jq6_xLllfIW9fatnb2-w4GhzKZMb5IIlACc_iKXTqYNmJSiEXsTVgSNoAF9KC9CEwIAQ8BxnKgVnhcCwANakHhgYC4AA2smRwhA7HkACMsEwGSsWMBacAmAAhISU7G4vBcrhCACCAA8IPjqK9YEyWTwAG5YWkMaTItFOFb8HkYFlE14yynmCUrADmTEYIBUGFIACJ-IJRKpnfrXuIpJS3UpRL6LMj0ML5LpLd6VhqtarI_odSsMejo4quCSPBSNDTNVaqCrKezOWn0Dy-YLwzxRXj82HZfLSKaVoX5LHtTxdaXYIbgMam6HYOaNIm61RbfbHS6A8pPd30MH_YplMGx2HKSYzKP57B26rN5bdc4UyjvTKGwrm8qhMyLaPKHrKNK5ZfnK31ZqO2msC-ADJYVkCFpJsT0fdBqV5SAQBA71aQIa1-CdZAwNgW1VAHWg4LMSlqgAUnzHFrU8Eh5CifC01ZGlqQkHDyLfUBKUqOjaB5AQsB8f9AOA5UmG1B8UDRABuIA)

Comment: You posted the same link twice. Its not at all clear to me what you want to achieve. Pls clarify on that with a more elaborate description of what you expect to happen or an image how it should look like.